# Is it possible in biblatex to print the \shorttitle in one's bibliography without defining a bibliography style?

Tags: biblatex

I would like all shorttitles, if one has been defined, to be printed in parentheses in the bibliography after the full title. Is this possible without having to define one's own bibliography style?

MME:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid,language=american]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Hicks1925,
address = {Cambridge, MA},
author = {Diogenes Laërtius},
publisher = {Harvard University Press},
series = {Loeb Classical Library},
shorttitle = {DL},
title = {{Lives of Eminent Philosophers}},
translator = {Hicks, R. D.},
volume = {II},
year = {1925}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\citetitle{Hicks1925}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

> Laërtius, Diogenes (1925). Lives of Eminent Philosophers. Trans. by R. D. Hicks. Vol. II. Loeb Classical Library. Cambridge, MA: Harvard University
>   Press.

while what I would like it to say is:

> Laërtius, Diogenes (1925). Lives of Eminent Philosophers (DL). Trans. by R. D. Hicks. Vol. II. Loeb Classical Library. Cambridge, MA: Harvard University
>   Press.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if you should be using the `shorttitle` field that way. Maybe `shorthand` is more appropriate?

Anyway, we can print the `shorttitle` directly after the title with this handy modification

```
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printfield[parens]{shorttitle}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}
```

That is the standard macro from `biblatex.def` with two lines added to also print the `shorttitle`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Hicks1925,
address = {Cambridge, MA},
author = {Diogenes Laërtius},
publisher = {Harvard University Press},
series = {Loeb Classical Library},
shorttitle = {DL},
title = {{Lives of Eminent Philosophers}},
translator = {Hicks, R. D.},
volume = {II},
year = {1925}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printfield[parens]{shorttitle}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

\begin{document}

\citetitle{Hicks1925}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: @Clément Not sure, to me "DL" seems more like an abbreviation of "Diogenes Laërtius" than like a short version of the actual title "Lives of Eminent Philosophers". The fact that the OP used `\citetitle` to cite the work made me think they always want to see "DL" instead of another label. In that case `shorthand` is very appropriate.

Comment: You're right, I misread the question by taking its title too literally. What OP is looking for can (should?) be achieved by using a different field than `shorttitle`.

Comment: @Clément Precisely, that is the reason for my introductory statement in the answer. But since both the title and the question are very clear about `shorttitle` I still answered the question as posted.

Comment: Thank you. You're absolutely right about `shorthand`, however, seeing as it's not an integrated definition in Mendeley (my choice of reference manager), I found my self forced to go with `shorttitle` instead. Hence, your answer is very much appreciated.
And to clarify: I realized that my question was actually rather unclear. What I hoped was possible was simply to add an argument to `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}` like `shorttitle=true`.

Comment: @Alexander A simple `shorttitle=true` is not possible, that is only implemented for a very limited set of fields (`url`, `doi`, `eprint` and a few others). For other fields you will have to redefine the appropriate macros. I strongly suggest you try and convince mendeley to support `shorthand` instead of going for kludges such as using the `shorttitle`, maybe the developers are open for feature requests in that direction.