# Biblatex authorless editorless books

Tags: biblatex, acronyms

I am writing an academic essay and I need to cite a number of books which either have neither author nor editor name associated with them or, if they have an editor, are still not naturally referred to in this fashion. Instead they are known by way of some common name. The main examples are different Bible editions which are commonly referred to by their abbreviations. NIV, ESV.

The citation style I use is generally Chicago style, i.e. (author year:page) or possibly within the text author (year:page), but with these I would like to use ESV (1984)

So, is there a way of creating a cite name which will then be used? Currently I use all kinds of fudges including putting the abbreviation into the author field. It kind of works, which is probably all I need, but I do like to do things "just right".

So, I guess what I am looking for is a Bibtex field into which I can put a "common name" and use that in preference to editors etc which might be named in the Bibliography, but will not be used for citing.

Suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't the `shorrttitle` field work here? E.g.: `shorttitle = {ESV},`. If not, please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks!! shorttitle does exatly what I need. This is brilliant.

Comment: With `biblatex` `shorthand` or `label` might be even better-suited. `label` replaces a missing name part in the label generation, so `label = {Foo}, year = {1999}` gives "Foo 1999" while `shorthand` replaces the entire label, so `shorthand = {Foo}, year = {1999}` gives "Foo". (A short discussion on `shorttitle` vs `shorthand` can be found in the comments [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277830/35864))

Comment: BTW: If you really use `biblatex` (as the title suggests) you might want to tag your question appropriately. If not you might want to change the title so as to not confuse future readers. In case you are using `biblatex` by "generally Chicago style" do you mean you are using `biblatex-chicago`, the standard `authoryear` or something home-grown? A short [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have so far, though not always necessary, can greatly help the understanding of your question.

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes you are using `biblatex-chicago`. If that is not true, please revise your answer accordingly. Since the question is about creating "short" titles, I assume you have in mind the traditional "notes and bibliography" style the *Chicago Manual of Style* is famous for.

The fields most relevant to your questions are the following:

```
shorttitle = {...},
shorthand  = {...},
label      = {...},
```

They do different things in different styles. In `biblatex-chicago`, the `shorttitle` field is what is used for subsequent citations and is usually an abbreviation of the full title. `shorthand` is useful when you want to give an ultrashort abbreviation for a frequently cited work. (It is worth pointint out that this field may decrease the portability of a general `.bib` file if special care is not taken.) Finally, `label` is useful for filling *lacunae* in a `.bib` entry (e.g., because a work has no author in an author-title style).

It is easiest to see in an example (relying on the annotated(!) `biblatex-example.bib` file that ships with `biblatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=18cm]{geometry}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Initial citation (label):         \autocite{cms, ctan}\par
Initial citation (shorttitle):    \autocite{springer}\par
Initial citation  (shorthand):    \autocite{kant:kpv}\par
Subsequent citation (shorttitle): \autocite{springer}\par
Subsequent citation  (shorthand): \autocite{kant:kpv}\par
Subsequent citation (Label):      \autocite{cms, ctan}
% \printshorthands
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```